# rpy2 - RRuntimeError: Error in colnames

Tags: python, r, rpy2

my setup is jupyter 4.0.0, python 2.7.6, rpy2 2.7.0, R 3.2.2

I am trying to use the package "imputeR".

When I use it from R directly, it works fine :

```
data = read.csv("./data/cs-training.csv")
data$SeriousDlqin2yrs <- NULL
imputed = impute(data, lmFun = "lassoR")
```

with the following output:

```
Imputation task is: Regression 
iteration 1 using lassoR in progress...done!
Difference after iteration 1 is 0.0006133373 
iteration 2 using lassoR in progress...done!
Difference after iteration 2 is 3.031679e-07 
iteration 3 using lassoR in progress...done!
Difference after iteration 3 is 6.417477e-11 
iteration 4 using lassoR in progress...done!
Difference after iteration 4 is 1.919108e-10
```

from python, by using rpy2, unfortunately it fails, and I haven't been able to solve the issue... any idea ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("../data/cs-training.csv")
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()

imputeR = importr('imputeR')
impute = imputeR.impute

imputeR.impute(df2i.as_matrix(),lmFun="lassoR")
```

This is the standard output I got

```
Imputation task is: Regression 
iteration 1 using lassoR in progress...
/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/venvpy2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-bd8bd78310aa> in <module>()
      8 df2i = df.drop("SeriousDlqin2yrs",axis=1)
      9 
---> 10 imputeR.impute(df2i.as_matrix(),lmFun="lassoR")

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/venvpy2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
    177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    179 
    180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/venvpy2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
    105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    108         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Comment: In R you are passing to `impute()` a data frame while in Python you are passing a matrix (or so one can guess from `df2i.as_matrix()`... there is no indication about about what is `df2i`).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply ! Analysing further the problem, I discover the problem was within the imputeR package. 
In particular, if a column has only one value missing, i.e. NA, then the impute function fails.